# How to add item to list with Null Safety

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I have problem working with null safety in dart.

```
void main() {
  List<String>? testlist;
  testlist?.add('null test');
  print(testlist);
}
```

Why the printed `testlist` is still null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `testlist` is still null, because you defined it as nullable and did not initialize it.

So when it comes to adding an entry to your `testlist`, while calling `testlist?.add('null test');`. A check will be performed, if `testlist` is null. If it is null, the call for `add` will be skipped. And in your case, it is always null.

So to visualize the null-conditional operator in your code line `testlist?.add('null test');`. It could also be written as:

```
List<String>? testlist;

// testlist?.add('null test');  
if(testlist != null) {
    testlist.add('null test');
}
  
print(testlist);
```

---

If you want to add the string, you have to initialize your `testlist`:

```
List<String>? testlist = [];
```

Or if possible you could avoid the nullable and write your code as:

```
List<String> testlist = [];
testlist.add('null test');
print(testlist);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't assigned a value to `testlist`, it's null and the `add` method is not executed.

The `add` method simply "adds" an entry to the list, but if the list is null you can't add anything to it.

You have to initialize it somehow, for example as `List<String>? testlist = [];`, but it depends how you'll use it in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays if you want to add to a list which is null (for example loading empty list from Shared Preferences on a first run) and don't have unnecessary  ifs, it can be done with this:

```
testlist ??= [];
testlist.add('null test');
print(testlist);
```